# Where is the SDL lib folder in SDL-1.2.15?

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm trying to run a SDL hello world example. Everywhere it says, I have to copy the lib folder of SDL to somewhere else. But there is no lib folder in SDL-1.2.15.

Have searched for this but don't find anything. Have also tried to run skipping the step with the lib folder, but doesn't build, because, it doesn't find the library. What am I doing wrong?

Using Windows 7 64 bit.

What I did:

Copied the contents of include in my mingw include directory.
This way I can include SDL in the source file without compiler errors.

Linked SDL library "SDL".

Added the .dll to both `C:\Windows\System32` and `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`

The code compiles but it fails with:

`c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lSDL`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah. Found it. I had to download the development package: SDL-devel-1.2.15-mingw32.tar.gz